# Release memory of an item within an array

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management

I'm aware of `del` and the `gc` module but I was wondering if you can release memory within an array while looping over it; not to be confused with releasing the memory of the array itself. I want to release the memory of the item in the array after its printed.  Here is a contrived example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
for item in array:
  print item
  del item
```

Will this release the memory of the items `foo`, `bar`, and `foobar`?

Comment: There's nothing to release. `item` will reference the next item in the list at each iteration. Unless I'm misunderstanding and you want to delete items in the original `array` at each iteration?

Comment: So basically you're wanting to do something with each item and then remove it from the list?

Comment: delete the memory of the items at the end of each iteration.  my whole assumption is that foo bar and foobar will be holding their own space in memory

Comment: will 'removing' it from the list release the memory?

Comment: you must be in desperate need of memory, if you try to work against the language in such a way. If you are memory-critical then don't use python, use C. But I bet, there are hundreds of better places to safe some memory in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to release the memory used by the item in the list is either to delete the list position (e.g. `del array[1]`) or to assign something else into it (e.g. `array[1] = None`).  If you don't care about whether the memory used by the list itself is reclaimed, then the second is faster since it won't require moving any memory.

In either case, as long as there are no other references to that object, then its memory will be freed. So:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
for index, item in enumerate(array):
    print item
    array[index] = None

# at the end of the loop, `item` still points to the final item
# so you might want to do the same to make sure it gets released
item = None
```

Comment: Note that small strings are cached in Python, so this will only free up memory related to one reference count.

Comment: And string literals are interned and won't be freed up regardless, but I assume this is just an example.

Comment: i have objects stored within the arrays i want to apply this to example to. and thanks kindall i believe this is what i'm looking for

Comment: Deleting the list position (`del array[index]`) while you're iterating through it is a bad idea.

Comment: Point taken... of course there are ways around that, too, but anyway it's why I went with the more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can check for yourself.

your code:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
for item in array:
    del item
print array # ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

deleting one element from `array`:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
del array[1]
print array # ['foo', 'foobar']
```

deleting everything from `array`:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
del array[:]
print array # []
```

**NOTE:**
`'foo'` will **not** be garbage collected (i.e. memory will not be released) when there's another reference to it:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
x = array[0]
del array[:]
print array # []
print x # foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to modify a list while you're iterating through it with a `for` loop, try something like this:

```
array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
while array:
    item = array.pop()
```

This will remove the items from the array while you're going through it, allowing them to be garbage collected. However, this will cause you to go through the list in reverse order. If that's an issue, then use `array.reverse()` first.

You **do not** want to use `array.pop(0)` - even though this allows you to go through the array in the normal order, it is orders of magnitude slower than popping from the end. That isn't true when the list is pretty small, but if that was the case you probably wouldn't be worried about memory usage in the first place.

Comment: yea but when does the garbage collect occur? after the loop is finished. i need it to be released after each iteration

Comment: @200OK I believe that `array.pop(0)` would take significantly longer than taking from the end.

Comment: @Joaq2Remember You could add `del item` to each iteration of the loop. My main point was that modifying a list while iterating through it (`for` loop) tends to be a bad idea.